# uploading pdf file using jquery mvc 4

Tags: c#, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to upload a file using jquery and it work fine with text file but when i try to upload a pdf file it gives an error and always return 0 to Request.Files.Count.

Actually I am trying to preview the document before uploading so first i upload a document in preview folder and after that i display it in the div using pdf viewer and if he select another document i will delete the last document and upload new document  but my problem is that my code only works with the .txt file and i want pdf

i try for 2 hours and dont understand the error please help!

**Client Side Code**

**HTML**

```
<input id="file" class="form-control-file" type="file" name="file" placeholder="Document Upload" />
```

**Jquery**

```
    $("#file").change(function () {
        var formData = new FormData();
        var totalFiles = document.getElementById("file").files.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++) {
            var file = document.getElementById("file").files[i];

            formData.append("file", file);
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/Admin/PreviewUpload',
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (response) {
                alert('succes!!');
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("errror");
            }
        });
    });
```

**Server Side Code**

```
  [HttpPost]   
  public ActionResult PreviewUpload()
    {
        if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (string files in Request.Files)
            {
                var _file = Request.Files[files];
                FileInfo Fi = new FileInfo(Path.GetFileName(_file.FileName));
                string fileExtention = Fi.Extension;
                if (_file != null)
                {
                    if (fileExtention == ".PDF")
                    {
                        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(_file.FileName);
                        if (_file.ContentLength <= 120000000)
                        {
                            _file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/PreviewPDF/" + fileName));
                        }
                        string path = "/PreviewPDF/" + Path.GetFileName(_file.FileName);
                        ViewData["error"] = path;
                        return Json(new
                        {
                            Success = path
                        });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return Json(new
                        {
                            fileError = "Only Support PDF"
                        });
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return Json(new
                    {
                        error = "Please Select the file"
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        return Json(new
        {
            error = "Please Select the file"
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please check your pdf file size maybe it's larger file default file uploading size in MVC application `4MB` you need to increase request length `maxRequestLength`.

Comment: OK brother thanks you very much it allow only 4 mb and when i upload 3 mb pdf file it works perfectly fine thanks <3 and FML I wasted  2 hours on this :(

Comment: Welcome Bhai if you want uploading >4 mb file you need to increase size in web.config file using maxRequestLength.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to upload a large file you need to change the configuration.

For more details click here [Click me](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc5-limit-upload-file-size/)

> You need to add/update the values of "executionTimeout",
>   "maxRequestLength" & "maxAllowedContentLength" properties if not
>   already added in the "Web.config" file, as shown below.

```
<system.web>  
  <authentication mode="None" />  
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />   // here your project version
  <!-- executionTimeout = 30hrs (the value is in seconds) and maxRequestLength = 1GB (the value is in Bytes) -->  
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" executionTimeout="108000" maxRequestLength="1073741824" />  
</system.web>     
<system.webServer>  
  <!-- maxAllowedContentLength = 1GB (the value is in Bytes) -->      
  <security>  
    <requestFiltering>  
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />  
    </requestFiltering>  
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```